# Split values in brackets into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column containing data encapsulated in `<::>`. I want to split these pieces into separate columns.

Data column looks like this:

```
<:abc:><:xyz:><:dds:>
<:dae:><:xr:><:s:>
```

Desired result

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
----------------
abc   xyz   dds
dae   xr    s
```

Comment: You could do something with this: https://appuals.com/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-delimited-char-in-sql-server/ I would suggest splitting on either of the <: or :> and then cut 2 characters from either the start or the end

Comment: Is the number of "colums" the same in all of the rows?

Comment: Yes - number of "columns" will be same in all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be carefull with `STRING_SPLIT()`. It does not guarantee to return the expected sort order.

My suggestion uses XML. Try this:

--Some test data in a declared table variable

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTo @tbl(YourString) VALUES('<:abc:><:xyz:><:dds:>'),
                                   ('<:dae:><:xr:><:s:>');
```

--the query

```
SELECT A.x.value('x[1]','varchar(1000)') AS col1
      ,A.x.value('x[2]','varchar(1000)') AS col2
      ,A.x.value('x[3]','varchar(1000)') AS col3
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,'<:','<x>'),':>','</x>') AS XML)) A(x);
```

The idea in short

- We replace your separators in order to get a castable XML.
- We use an APPLY to add this casted XML to our result set.
- We fetch each element by its position (XQuery)

Starting with v2016 the recommended approach uses JSON for this:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(A.j,'$[0]') AS col1
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.j,'$[1]') AS col2
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.j,'$[2]') AS col3
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,':><:','","'),'<:','["'),':>','"]')) A(j);
```

... or this (see the doubled square brackets):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,':><:','","'),'<:','[["'),':>','"]]'))
            WITH(col1 VARCHAR(1000) '$[0]'
                ,col2 VARCHAR(1000) '$[1]'
                ,col3 VARCHAR(1000) '$[2]') A;
```

The idea is the same...

Hint: Within XML (elements) and JSON-arrays the sort order is secure.

Comment: very well done - I could apply your solution to my problem. Using a CTE I was able to combine the split columns with some columns of the source table.
I paste my final query at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `string_split` for this however it's not guaranteed to always return rows in the same order so I prefer to use *OpenJson* for small data sets as it provides a consistent index.

```
with d as (
    select '[' + Stuff(Translate(data,':<>','", '),1,1,'') + ']' data
    from t
)
select 
    max(case when j.[key]=0 then j.[value] end) Col1,
    max(case when j.[key]=1 then j.[value] end) Col2,
    max(case when j.[key]=2 then j.[value] end) Col3
from d
cross apply OpenJson(d.data)j
group by d.data
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00b48afa4f4e82ae26f65102d49ac510)

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as (
SELECT A.x.value('x[1]','varchar(500)') AS P01
      ,A.x.value('x[2]','varchar(500)') AS P02
      ,A.x.value('x[3]','varchar(500)') AS P03
      ,A.x.value('x[4]','varchar(500)') AS P04
      ,A.x.value('x[5]','varchar(500)') AS P05
      ,t.*
FROM [LIST] t

CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.[JOB_PARAMETER],'<:','<x>'),':>','</x>') AS XML)) A(x)
  
 )
SELECT [ID]
      ,[TYP]
      ,[PARAMETER]
     ,P01
     ,P02
     ,P03
     ,P04
     ,P05


FROM CTE
```